# Caliburn Micro with custom RootFrame breaks RootVisual - WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to get Caliburn.Micro 2.0 to work with [SlideApplicationFrame](https://slideview.codeplex.com/)

In Caliburn AppBootstrapper I override PhoneApplicationFrame:

```
protected override PhoneApplicationFrame CreatePhoneApplicationFrame()
    {
        return new SlideApplicationFrame();
    }
```

This will result in having a RootFrame with the slide behaviour which works as expected.

In App.xaml I reference to the SlideView library:

```
xmlns:library="clr-namespace:SlideView.Library;assembly=SlideView.Library"
```

Then I load the SlideApplicationFrame content into the RootVisual:

```
<Application.RootVisual>
    <library:SlideApplicationFrame Header="Test App" Background="White">
        <library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
            <TextBlock Text="Right" Width="200"/>
        </library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
        <library:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>
            <TextBlock Text="Left" Width="200"/>
        </library:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>
    </library:SlideApplicationFrame>
</Application.RootVisual>
```

This doesn't work! But If I load a simple rectangle it wil be displayed before the first page is loaded.

```
<Application.RootVisual>
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Application.RootVisual>
```

Do I need to add an additional override which will add the content to the RootVisual?

Can't think straight anymore.  Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE 19 Oct 2014:

I figured out that RootVisual is set by Caliburn Micro. So as mvermef pointed out there is no need for any RootVisual code in App.xaml. I removed that part.

I changed the override CreatePhoneApplicationFrame to:

```
protected override PhoneApplicationFrame CreatePhoneApplicationFrame()
    {
        SlideApplicationFrame frame = new SlideApplicationFrame();

        frame.Header = "Test";

        Rectangle testing = new Rectangle();

        testing.Width = 100;

        testing.Height = 100;

        testing.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,208,208,208));

        frame.LeftContent = testing;

        return frame;
    }
```

This will give a rectangle in the LeftContent view of the SlideApplicationFrame. I now need to find out how I can load a Caliburn view as content..

So no I need to figure out how it plays nice with the MainPage. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe try asking the Caliburn guys if this is even possible https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues

Comment: definitely doesn't play nice... I think the example is just bad... As far as I can tell it isn't a Caliburn thing more of a sequence of how to properly integrate the control.  Wp81 example does it differently than wp8....

Comment: Did some more testing with WP8 but can't get it to work... Thanks for pointing out to the WP8.1 example, I will go down the path to WP8.1. Hopefully it will be a path forward with eventually some backward capability :). Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling you don't need anything in the App.xaml, other than in the shellview or mainview what ever you use.  To frame out the view structure.  I might play with it some more, but haven't had the free time.

Comment: I found that the Nuget packages are hosed... I downloaded the source and recompiled, using the App.xaml Resources you can put a "Template" using the term loosely. You can get it to function but I am still having issues with binding to the ContentControls that I place into the "Template".  I don't believe it is the best solution at present.  Again the nuget packages doesn't play well, especially for windows phone Silverlight 8.1, it completely wrong assembly getting plugged into the project. ```<sv:SlideApplicationFrame x:Key="Root">..reference wp81 example</sv:SlideApplicationFrame>```

Comment: I also tried an older release of slideview which had an Shell concept but it still doesn't play nice. Decided to stop combining the slideview with caliburn and using mvvmlight now. That works without any problem and headaches :). A little more coding effort but i'm getting there now.